# Php-Mysql: date field updated with 0000-00-00 instead of the correct/requested date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in phpMyAdmin containing (among other fields) two date fields (let's call them date1 and date2) of type "date" and default value "null".
In php, I want to update these date fields:

```
$query6 = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE biblioteca SET date1=CURDATE(), date2=CURDATE()+14 WHERE id_carte=$id_carte");
```

For date1, everything works ok (the current date is introduced in the table in the format 2017-12-29), but for date2 it is introduced in the database 0000-00-00. I have tried to set date2 also to the CURDATE(), but it has the same effect. I have also checked to see if the fields date1 and date2 have the same characteristics in the database and they do.

Could somebody figure out what could be the problem?

Comment: You should start by fixing the root of your problem: your server should be running in [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

Comment: post the schema for this. I suspect you're storing as VARCHAR.

Comment: @tereško. I have opened the mysql console and I gave introduced the following command:

    SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';

It returned "Query OK", but it still introduces 0000-00-00. Is this the correct way to set the strict mode?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner. The type of the date1 and date2 in the database is "date".

Comment: I have made some tests and the behavior is the following: if date1 is set to a date from 2018 everything works ok. But why?

Comment: Weird. Do you have any triggers defined?

Comment: You are right, I have a trigger defined:

    SET NEW.date2 = NEW.date1 + 14;

with time "BEFORE" and event "UPDATE".
I have forgotten about this as I have introduced it approx. 2 years ago.
Now I try to figure out how it really works and how it influences the behavior.

Comment: I have removed the trigger and it works perfect. Thanks a lot.
Nevertheless, is it possible to have a trigger which automatically updates date2 when date1 is being updated? Something similar with what I have tried, but in my implementation did not work

Comment: Yes, it of course it is possible to have trigger to do so, but you must pay attention and use the dates correctly. You cannot add a number to a date like I mentioned in my answer. If you need help with the trigger, post it in a new question so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

When you add a number to the date, the result is a number, not a date. Use the `DATE_ADD()` instead:

```
UPDATE biblioteca SET date1=CURDATE(), date2=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) WHERE ...
```

Comment: The problem was that I had a trigger about which I have forgotten and it seems that this trigger produced this strange behavior. Nevertheless, thanks for the solution provided; I have learned from it also.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper date_add(..) function for add  day to curdate()

```
"UPDATE biblioteca SET date1=CURDATE(), date2=date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
  WHERE id_carte=$id_carte");
```

The behavior you describe is weird  .. then try using a date part  from now()

```
"UPDATE biblioteca 
  SET date1=date(now()) , date2=date_add(date(now(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
 WHERE id_carte=$id_carte");
```

Comment: I have tried, but still not working. Another test I have done is to add 14 days to date1. Also, this is not working (result 0000-00-00 also for date1). Another test was to run this code:

    "UPDATE biblioteca SET date1=date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) , date2=date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
  WHERE id_carte=$id_carte");

and surprisingly it works! I'm lost.

Comment: I have made even more tests and the behavior is the following: if date1 is set to a date from 2018 everything works ok. But why?

Comment: @AdiS.  answer  update  with a suggestion  .. (could be you need restart your ide ..or sql console too)

Comment: The problem was that I had a trigger about which I have forgotten and it seems that this trigger produced this strange behavior. Nevertheless, thanks for the solution provided; I have learned from it also.